# Common Lisp: How to build a list in a macro with conditional splicing?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, splice

Let's assume:

```
(defmacro testing (&optional var)
    `(list 'this 'is  
       ,@(when (consp var) `('a 'list))))
```

when called:

```
>(testing 2)
(THIS IS)

>(testing (list 1 2))
(THIS IS A LIST)
```

which is what I wanted. But now, when I pass a parameter that is a list:

```
>(defparameter bla (list 1 2 3))
BLA
>(testing bla)
(THIS IS)
```

which I suppose is because the macro would check `(consp bla)` where bla is a symbol, instead of the list? How do I prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
(defmacro testing (&optional var)
   `(if (consp ,var)
        '(this is a list)
        '(this is)))
```

So `var` will be evaluated at run time (not compile time). `var` only appears one time in the expansion of the macro, but if it appeared more than once, you would have to use a gensym.

EDIT: If you don't want to type `'(this is)` twice, do this:

```
(defmacro testing (&optional var)
  `(append '(this is) (when (consp ,var) '(a list))))
```

Don't use `eval`, it's slow, and completely unnecessary. By substituting `var` into the macro expansion, it will naturally be evaluated at run-time. If you use eval, you will be doing something like this:

```
(eval (append '(list 'this 'is) (when (consp 'bla) '('a 'list))))
```

*Every* time that executes, it will build up a list representing the code and compile it before running it. (Hopefully this isn't in a loop!) If you just use a macro which generates straightforward code (without `eval`), it will compile only once.

Comment: This would work in this (very simplified) case, but I'm trying to prevent having to type '(this is) twice with conditional splicing.

Comment: @mck, I just posted code for you which meets that requirement.

Comment: Thank you, an elegant solution. Could be even shorter by replacing the if with when, and dropping the nil (when returns nil when false). One more question about "naturally evaluated at run-time". When I try this on some code, it returns the list nicely, but fails to evaluate it?

Comment: @mck, what do you mean it fails to evaluate it? `(testing (list 1 2)) ; => (this is a list)` You can see here that `(list 1 2)` has been evaluated, the result was `consp`, so it returns `(this is a list)`. Can you post the code which you were trying?

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221815/common-lisp-how-to-build-a-loop-expression-with-a-macro) is a follow up question where my macro doesn't seem to run if I don't use eval. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just posted an answer to the follow-up question. Many good books on Lisp will advise you that using `eval` is usually a bad idea. That's certainly true in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the expression

```
,@(when (consp var) `('a 'list))))
```

is evaluated at compile time, when you only have literal (unevaluated) values of arguments. In your case: `2`, `(list 1 2)`, and `bla`.

The only solution to this, that I'm aware of, is to use `eval`. This particular example can be changed as follows:

```
(defmacro testing (&optional var)
  `(eval (append '(list 'this 'is)  
                 (when (consp ',var)
                   '('a 'list))))
```

But, I think, you'll agree, that its really ugly. And it won't work if you want to use lexical variables. Usually, there are ways to reformulate the problem, so that such perversions aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick (though I think the ' after consp needs to go?). I was hoping for something more elegant, but perhaps I should indeed try to reformulate it..

Comment: Regarding the quote - it depends on how you'd like to pass the data. In your case it's not really needed - that's true. But oftentimes you'll see that in macros, which expect "lightweight" lists, like `(1 2 3)`