# Common Lisp: How to build a loop expression with a macro?

Tags: loops, macros, common-lisp

This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214673/common-lisp-how-to-build-a-list-in-a-macro-with-conditional-splicing), some sort of a follow up.

Let's say I'm trying to build a loop expression by using macros, in which the resulting loop expression is dependant on whether the parameter is a list:

```
(defmacro testing-loop (var)
   `(eval (append '(loop for x from 0 to 5)
            (when (consp ,var) '(and y in ,var))            
            '(collect)            
            (if (consp ,var) '(y) '(x))))
```

This seems to work:

```
CL-USER> (testing-loop 2)
(0 1 2 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (testing-loop (list 5 6 7))
(5 6 7)
```

But when applying this macro in a lexical closure, it breaks down:

```
CL-USER> (let ((bar (list 1 2 3)))
           (testing-loop bar))
```

which throws undefined variable: BAR

I expected `testing-loop` to macroexpand into the lexical scope where bar is bound?

Comment: You have a call to `EVAL` there. `EVAL` always evaluates the form in the null lexical environment. Frankly, I don't really understand why you have the eval there in the first place.

Comment: @Elias Mårtenson: I think the `eval` was suggested to mck in the answers to the previous question. @mck: if you're trying to learn about macros by trying to figure out use cases for them and then find solutions for those use cases, maybe you should read [OnLisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html) and/or [Let Over Lambda](http://letoverlambda.com/). They cover a lot of interesting ground - I recommend starting with OnLisp, though.

Comment: @EliasMårtenson: Thanks for the comment, I didn't know `eval` evaluates in the null lexical environment; learned something new. However, if I don't put `eval` there, the macro returns the list of the code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mck, I see why you want to use `eval` now. But it's a very messy solution, and slow, as I mentioned in my answer to the previous question. The classic *On Lisp* says this about `eval`:

"Generally it is not a good idea to call eval at runtime, for two reasons:

1. It’s inefficient: eval is handed a raw list, and either has to compile it on the
   spot, or evaluate it in an interpreter. Either way is slower than compiling
   the code beforehand, and just calling it.
2. It’s less powerful, because the expression is evaluated with no lexical context.
   Among other things, this means that you can’t refer to ordinary
   variables visible outside the expression being evaluated.

Usually, calling eval explicitly is like buying something in an airport gift-shop.
Having waited till the last moment, you have to pay high prices for a limited
selection of second-rate goods."

In this case the simplest thing is just to:

```
(defmacro testing-loop (var)
  (let ((g (gensym)))
   `(let ((,g ,var))
      (if (consp ,g)
        (loop for x from 0 to 5 collect x)
        (loop for x from 0 to 5 and y in ,g collect y)))))
```

I know you want to factor out the common `loop for x from 0 to 5` (which isn't actually needed in the second branch anyways). But `loop` is itself a macro which is converted *at compile time* to efficient, low level code. So the call to `loop` has to be built *at compile time*, using values which are available at compile time. You can't just insert an `(if)` in there which is intended to be evaluated at run time.

If you really don't want to repeat `loop for x from 0 to 5`, you could do something like:

```
(let ((a '(loop for x from 0 to 5)))
  `(if (consp ,var)
       (,@a collect x)
       (,@a and y in ,var collect y)))
```

That's just to give you the idea; if you really do this, make sure to `gensym`!

A good lesson to learn from this is: when you are writing macros, you need to keep clearly in mind what is happening at compile time and what is happening at run time. The macro you wrote with `eval` compiles the `loop` macro dynamically, *every time it is run*, based on the return value of `consp`. You really want to compile the 2 different `loop` macros once, and just select the correct one at run-time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the terrific answer!

Comment: Alex, if I'm not mistaken, fexprs allow the IF to be done at expansion time yes?

Comment: @PaulNathan, mck wants the `loop` which is executed to be determined by the *run-time value* of an expression. If you look back at the "related question", that will give you an idea what he is trying to do.